# Under what conditions might res.status() or res.json() throw/raise an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httpresponse

I have this generic function I have for a library:

```
const sendResponse = (res: Response, errorTrace: InspectedError) => {

  if (res.headersSent) {
    log.warning('Headers already sent for response. Error:', errorTrace);
  }

  try {
    res.status(500);  // this one
  } catch (err) {
    log.error(err);
  }

  try {
    res.json({      // this one
      foo: 'bar'
    });

  } catch (err) {
    log.error(err);
  }

};
```

I am curious what kinds of errors might be raised by res.status() and res.json() - is the best bet to look at the source or is there a better way to find out?

Comment: Just in case this is not a hypothetical and this is real code you're running into, this does not seem like good code and they feel like unneeded catch statements. It's better to catch these really-exceptional case higher up in your application and not for every case.

Comment: Even libraries should _generally_ throw on unexpected cases. It's not *usually* the responsibility for libraries to catch and obscure major issues, unless that's specifically the purpose of your library. Given that you can't even think of *why* these cases might throw, I doubt this is the case for you. But could be wrong ofcourse because I don't fully know your use-case. Just a bit red-flaggy (I hope this is helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some situations I can think of:

1. `res` is invalid and either isn't an object or doesn't have a `status` or `json` method.
2. `res.json()` can fail if you give it an invalid parameter or you give it an object that contains circular references (that can't be represented in JSON).

Comment: can the status code be set more than once? successuly?

Comment: your last statement is very wrong - I would like to try to set the statuscode, that could fail, but I still would want to attempt to send the response with .json()

Comment: @AlexanderMills - Yes, it can.  All it does is set a property to remember what the status should be when the final response is sent.  You can call it multiple times and the last one wins.

Comment: I always found that interesting, since http responses can be streamed, and the status code is usually first thing received, so I guess you can change status code as much as you want until you call .write()

Comment: @AlexanderMills - OK, I didn't realize you were trying to execute both `res.status(500)` AND `res.json(...)`.  I would have written `res.status(500).json(...)` with one try/catch around it.   If `res.status(500)` fails you have much bigger problems because apparently `res` is not valid so I don't see the need to separately `try/catch` it.

Comment: @AlexanderMills - You know you can just step into `res.status(500)` in the debugger and watch what it does.  That's way more educational than reading any doc or getting answers here.  It's THE way to actually know what it might do.  And, I find it easier than trying to find the relevant nodejs/Express source code on github.